# SQL and LIKE with alias

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-like

I'm trying to use alias in a LIKE but this doesn't work. I heard alias arent allowed in the WHERE clause, so how can I make my SQL request work?

```
SELECT i.tag as mytag
FROM tags as t, images as i 
WHERE i.id = 15 
AND i.tag LIKE "%;myid;%"
```

What I try to do here is to select the tag if it is present in the tags of image number 15. (tags of images are like ";15;2;4;" , that's why I write the ' LIKE "%;myid;%" ' ).

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just refer to the original column and not its alias ?

```
SELECT i.tag as mytag, t.id as myid 
FROM tags as t, images as i 
WHERE i.id = 15 
AND i.tag LIKE concat_ws(";", "%", t.id, "%")
```

Comment: I try that with comma instead of + (for MySql) but I got another error :
Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Comment: Updated to reflect mysql syntax, but i'm not mysql expert, let me know

Comment: At least you orientate me in the good direction. Thanks for that.